# Unexpected order when using DataFrame.sort_index(axis=1). First column listed last

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample DataFrame populated like so:

```
               Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta   Epsilon
Date
2017-01-02  0.854046       NaN  0.681606  0.883779  0.680304
2017-01-01  0.573784  0.407917  0.446668  0.463504  0.136830
2017-01-03  0.556100  0.849009  0.389748       NaN  0.777201
```

When I sort by axis=1 (column headers) the 'Alpha' column is being put in the last position:

```
df_sorted = df1.sort_index(axis=1)
print df_sorted
```

Output:

```
                Beta     Delta   Epsilon     Gamma     Alpha
Date
2017-01-02       NaN  0.883779  0.680304  0.681606  0.854046
2017-01-01  0.407917  0.463504  0.136830  0.446668  0.573784
2017-01-03  0.849009       NaN  0.777201  0.389748  0.556100
```

Can anyone explain the Alphanumeric sorting of the columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what your `df1.columns` is and `pd.__version__`?

Comment: You use an old version of pandas for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have whitespace in front of some column names, using @rahlf23 setup with some modifications:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-01-02',  ' 0.854046',       np.nan,  '0.681606',  '0.883779',  '0.680304'],
                    ['2017-01-01',  '0.573784',  '0.407917',  '0.446668',  '0.463504',  '0.136830'],
                    ['2017-01-03',  '0.556100',  '0.849009',  '0.389748',       np.nan,  '0.777201']],
                    columns=['Date', ' Beta',      ' Gamma',     ' Delta',     'Alpha',   ' Epsilon']).set_index('Date')

df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                 Beta     Delta   Epsilon     Gamma     Alpha
Date                                                         
2017-01-02   0.854046  0.681606  0.680304       NaN  0.883779
2017-01-01   0.573784  0.446668  0.136830  0.407917  0.463504
2017-01-03   0.556100  0.389748  0.777201  0.849009       NaN
```

To identify this you can use `df.to_dict()`:

```
{' Beta': {'2017-01-01': '0.573784',
  '2017-01-02': ' 0.854046',
  '2017-01-03': '0.556100'},
 ' Delta': {'2017-01-01': '0.446668',
  '2017-01-02': '0.681606',
  '2017-01-03': '0.389748'},
 ' Epsilon': {'2017-01-01': '0.136830',
  '2017-01-02': '0.680304',
  '2017-01-03': '0.777201'},
 ' Gamma': {'2017-01-01': '0.407917',
  '2017-01-02': nan,
  '2017-01-03': '0.849009'},
 'Alpha': {'2017-01-01': '0.463504',
  '2017-01-02': '0.883779',
  '2017-01-03': nan}}
```

And to fix, you can use .str.strip()

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               Alpha       Beta     Delta   Epsilon     Gamma
Date                                                         
2017-01-02  0.883779   0.854046  0.681606  0.680304       NaN
2017-01-01  0.463504   0.573784  0.446668  0.136830  0.407917
2017-01-03       NaN   0.556100  0.389748  0.777201  0.849009
```

Comment: This is exactly right. I had leading spaces which threw it off.  Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: @BenFinkel Awesome.  Glad I could help.   Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to reproduce your issue (Python 3.6.2, pandas 0.23.1), see below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-01-02',  ' 0.854046',       np.nan,  '0.681606',  '0.883779',  '0.680304'],
                    ['2017-01-01',  '0.573784',  '0.407917',  '0.446668',  '0.463504',  '0.136830'],
                    ['2017-01-03',  '0.556100',  '0.849009',  '0.389748',       np.nan,  '0.777201']],
                    columns=['Date', 'Alpha',      'Beta',     'Gamma',     'Delta',   'Epsilon']).set_index('Date')
```

Gives:

```
                Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta   Epsilon
Date                                                         
2017-01-02   0.854046       NaN  0.681606  0.883779  0.680304
2017-01-01   0.573784  0.407917  0.446668  0.463504  0.136830
2017-01-03   0.556100  0.849009  0.389748       NaN  0.777201
```

Sorting index:

```
df.sort_index()
```

Gives:

```
                Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta   Epsilon
Date                                                         
2017-01-01   0.573784  0.407917  0.446668  0.463504  0.136830
2017-01-02   0.854046       NaN  0.681606  0.883779  0.680304
2017-01-03   0.556100  0.849009  0.389748       NaN  0.777201
```

And sorting columns:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Gives:

```
                Alpha      Beta     Delta   Epsilon     Gamma
Date                                                         
2017-01-02   0.854046       NaN  0.883779  0.680304  0.681606
2017-01-01   0.573784  0.407917  0.463504  0.136830  0.446668
2017-01-03   0.556100  0.849009       NaN  0.777201  0.389748
```